# Shortening URL in Code Igniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working on a CodeIgniter framework for a website. I uploaded my website and it works. now what I want to do is to make some kind of secret URL shortcut that only several people know but still easy to remember. I want to make www.mywebsite.com/secretpage to load up my secret page. however codeigniter doesn't seems to allow direct access to files. I heard I can use the url routing using .htaccess but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: what doesn't seems to work? What have you tried paste that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the codeigniter Routes http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html Can shorten URLS. Add url helper to autoload.

You can't get direct access to the php because the code at the top of the controller blocks it.

example why you can not get direct access.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

How to shorten routes Example.

www.yourdomain.com/secretpage/

```
$route['secretpage'] = "folder/controller/index";

$route['secretpage'] = "folder/controller/index";
```

Also use htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

remove the index.php from the config file.